# Intent.getIntExtra() behaviour changes on a virtual device and on a real device

Tags: java, android

I have the below code and on my computer via Eclipse virtual device it works fine. But when installed on a real life phone it always reverts to the else statement.
This activity does not always get passed a value and if it is not I want a random record to appear. Thank you for any help or advice and time taken to read.

```
    searchId = getIntent().getIntExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", 0);

    if(searchId > 0){
        Query="SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE +" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
        Log.v("STANDARD RANDOM", "Was run");
    }
    else{   
        Query ="SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE +" WHERE _id=" + searchId + "";

        Log.v("FROM SEARCH PAGE", "Was run");
    }
```

Comment: This is not a problem with `if`; this is a change in behaviour of `getIntExtra`.  I've updated your question title accordingly.

Comment: Means getIntent().getIntExtra() always returns you 0, have you figured out why?

Comment: What does it print when you put `Log.v("STANDARD RANDOM", Integer.toString(searchId));` before the if statement?

Comment: Reading the piece of code where you are creating the Intent would help.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have tried many different solutions. In the end I got so confused I have realised I just put the wrong contents in each if and else statement. Copied and reversed everything works now. Still unsure why it worked on the emulator, but alls well now. Again thanks for everyones tips and time

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fixes your problem. But according to the documentation, your code is not correct:

> The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Taken from [Intent.putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

You are using "EMPLOYEE_ID", without a package prefix, but you **must** include one!